# UpperBody detection using haar cascade

Tags: computer-vision, opencv3.0

I'm trying to detect the upper body using haar cascade.
But still I'm not getting any detection on the image.

```
import numpy as np


import cv2

cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_upperbody.xml');

imgPath = '/home/ayush/Desktop/images.jpeg';
img = cv2.imread(imgPath);
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

body = cascade.detectMultiScale(
    gray,
    scaleFactor = 1.1,
    minNeighbors = 5,
    minSize = (30,30),
    flags = cv2.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE
)

for (x, y, w, h) in body:
    cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)

cv2.imshow('Upper Body',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Why is it so?
I'm using OpenCV3.

Comment: Try in on a series of images or video. It might not work for this image. If you do not have other images, try to rotate the image by +/- 15 degrees and try with that. Post your image here. Also remove params minSize and flags initially. When you get the detection you can optimise later.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that your `scaleFactor` is too small. I tried running your code exactly (though with my own image) and found no results at `1.1`, but found results at `1.01`.

See [here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/10654/how-does-the-parameter-scalefactor-in-detectmultiscale-affect-face-detection/) for a description of how the parameter affects your results.

Answer (score 1):

That's because the file **haarcascade_upperbody.xml** is trained to be used with pedestrian detection, and very probably your image is not matching to this case.